# Loading CSV into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I'm loading a simple csv into mysql. This is the csv:

```
NAME1;301106
NAME2;300374
NAME3;300966
```

And so on.

I thought this php file would do the trick, but nothing is added to the database table. There must be some obvious error. Have tried so many things, but with no result. Can anyone see the error?

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("........");  

mysqli_query($conn, '
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:/Users/Stephan/Desktop/student_magister.csv" 
INTO TABLE students
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";"
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
');
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does your script do anything at all? Does your query return true when it runs? Can you run that same SQL from the command line and have it work?

Comment: For a fraction of a sec it says 500 (internal server error)

Comment: Have you checked your error logs, in that case?

Comment: The connection is fine. The query error check doesn't return anything.

Comment: What query error check? If you've changed your code, could you edit the current code into your question?